# PHP Cron Job Error

Tags: php, cron

I want to execute a cron job, but I recieved an e-mail that tells me:

> No input file specified.

And I run the following cron command every day at 15:00

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/popasur/public_html/analytics/savedata_script.php?paramz=savesmdata
```

If I remove the "?" I recieve an e-mail with the output, but I also recieve this warning:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **/home/popasur/public_html/analytics/savedata_script.php** on line **15**

```
        $arguments = array();
    if (is_array($argv) && !empty($argv)) {
        foreach ($argv as $a) {
            $a_explode = explode("=", $a);
            $arguments[$a_explode[0]] = $a_explode[1]; //line 15
        }
    }
```

Comment: It means  $a_explode haven't any index 1. tr to do if(count($a_explode[1])>2){ $arguments[$a_explode[0]] = $a_explode[1];

Comment: And how I solve that notice? ... That if doesn't solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `$argv`, you should run your script like this:

```
php myScript.php arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

In this situation, you have:

```
$argv[0] // myScript.php
$argv[1] // arg1
$argv[2] // arg2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not usually how you pass parameters on the command line.  The reason your script isnt running is that the shell is trying to find a file called `/home/popasur/public_html/analytics/savedata_script.php?paramz=savesmdata`

and what I think you want is :

```
/home/popasur/public_html/analytics/savedata_script.php paramz=savesmdata
```

Then perform whatever exploding you want on $argv[1]

(or use something like getopts to do it properly)